# android onclicklistener hierarchy in nested views

Tags: android

How is onclicklistner hierarchy handled in nested views.  For example:

```
TableRow tr = something

tr.setOnClickListener()...

TableLayout tbl

tbl.addView(tr)

ScrollView sv

sv.addView(tbl)

sv.setOnClickListener()...
```

So, there are two levels of listeners in this example: one on each of the rows, and one on the "highest" container, sv.  The onclick events for the rows work, but the one on the sv appears to do nothing.  So, what happens to the listener on the sv, and how to manage both layer events?  Do nested onclicks "block" each other somehow?

Answer (score 0):

you need to set onTouchListener on your your TableRow, check if the view passed by onTouch method is the view you want. if so, process it to your onClick method

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants
```

in root "sv" layout . That will make parent clicks possible and separately u can handle row click/onTouch to add click listener for table row seperately.

Hope it helps ;) if So then pleas mark it as true or Vote Up.

Cheers